# Bootstrap navbar dropdown populated with database entries in Django 2

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, sqlite, navbar

I am trying to populate a navbar "dropdown-menu" with individual "dropdown-item"'s populated from data in the sqlite3 DB.

I have something similar working on other pages but I cant get it to work in my navbar.

I am creating a record label, and want the list of artists populated from entries in the DB. I have found one tutorial on doing something similar in php, but doesn't translate, and there doesn't seem to be anything either on youtube or here other than populating form data.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I have been trying to get it working for about a week now. I know it should be simple, but im missing something.

the app is called "music"

models.py

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    artist_logo = models.FileField()
    artist_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name

class Release(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    release_cover = models.FileField()
    release_duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.release_title

class Track(models.Model):
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    track_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    track_version = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    track_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    track_duration = models.IntegerField()
    track_number = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["track_number"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.track_title
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import ListView, View
from .models import Artist, Track, Release
from .forms import UserForm

# class IndexView(ListView):
#     template_name = 'music/index.html'

class ReleaseView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/releaselist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_releases'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Release.objects.all()

class ArtistView(generic.ListView):
    model = Artist
    template_name = 'music/artistlist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_artists'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Artist.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Release
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'
```

urls.py (Main)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# include urls from the music app
    path('music/', include('music.urls'))
```

urls.py ("music" aka the app urls)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views

# defined the app name in case the same fields are used in other apps
app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    # no info past music return index EG /music/
    # path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # albums/releases
    re_path(r'^release/$', views.ReleaseView.as_view(), name='release'),
    # looking for music page with album id afterwards /music/1
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ArtistView.as_view(), name="artist"),
```

base.html

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Artists
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            {% for artist in all_artists %}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ artist.artist_id }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </li>
```

Update:
Here is my releases.html which works using similar code, and at the bottom has a test which looks like the for loop is incorrect

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}KOLD FUZEON: Releases{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

        {% if all_releases %}
            <ul>
                {% for release in all_releases %}
                    <div class="releaseitem">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' release.id %}">{{ release.artist }} - {{ release.release_title }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' release.id %}"</a><img src="{{ release.release_cover.url }}" style="width: 300px"></li>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <h3>We currently dont have any releases yet.</h3>
        {% endif %}


{#basic test for the artist list to be printed to screen#}
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                {% for artist in all_artists %}
                    <li>test2</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your Template `base.html`, try **`{{artist.artist_name}}`** instead of `{{ artist.artist_id }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that and its still the same. I tried putting a test list item in with plain text and it doesn't work inside the for loop but does outside the for loop.

Comment: brother, let me work on your code. Give me Some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `View.py` you have `ArtistView` where **template** is `artistlist.html` and your context is `all_artist` & you get all objects from db.

**Code:**

```
class ArtistView(generic.ListView):
model = Artist
template_name = 'music/artistlist.html'
context_object_name = 'all_artists'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Artist.objects.all()
```

Now i believe you have a template named `artistlist.html`. If not create it in `templates` in which you will use **for Loop**
to render artist list so the code should be this for `artistlist.html`:

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

   <h1>Artists!</h1>

<ul>
{% for artist in all_artists %}
  <li class="artist">
     <h1>
         <a href='/music/{{ artist.id }}'>{{artist.artist_name }}</a>  
     </h1>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**You can Render Artist list in `Base.html`**.
Using: **`Context Processor`**

> First Create a file named `context_processors.py` in your `App`.Then add this code in that file.

```
from .models import Artist

def basetest(request):

    hello = Artist.objects.values_list("artist_name", flat=True)
    return {
        'testname': hello
    }
```

After that, open `Settings.py` and find **`context_processors`** and add the following settings `'yourapp.context_processors.add_variable_to_context'`.

**Settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

            #This one is from my code so set it according to you
            #appname.context_processors.function_name_context_processor.py',

            'blog.context_processors.basetest',

        ],
    },
},
]
```

After this just place **`{{ testname }}`** in your `base.html` according to your need.  it will work. No need for looping just the interpolation will render you a list. Format it according to your need by following this **[doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only)**

Comment: Apologies, i forgot to mention that my end goal is to have it in a separate file. I was trying to just get it working in my base.html first as I can create a block item for it later in a separate file.

I have changed it to the above now but still get no result.

I have opened the python console and get results when searching for Artist.objects.all()<br/>

In [10]: Artist.objects.all()<br/>
Out[10]: <QuerySet [<Artist: Daemon Chills>, <Artist: Acidshell>]><br/>

Comment: @DesCahill, i have updated the code to render model data in your `base.html`.

Comment: Hi Ans2Human

I wanted to take some time to have a good go at what you mentioned above in your latest update using the context processors.

I have tried what you are saying and I get a response with:

    <QuerySet [<Artist: Daemon Chills>, <Artist: Acidshell>]>

but it shows up as plain text which is interesting but i don't know how to work with that to create a separate <li> item with hyperlink for each item.

Comment: @DesCahill Link provided at the end of question is for you to understand how can you format the data and to create links i have updated my ans for that. The answer solves your main query of rendering data on `base.html`.

Comment: Sure thing, I saw that, so thanks for the help, but I dont know how to work with that and dont understand the reference on the other page, so I am going to try and get the for loop working, as that is more along the line of what i understand.

Comment: @DesCahill, help me by accepting the answer as it solved your primary problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help that you have provided but it is not a solution, and I still am no further towards a solution, and want to see if others can assist with helping me get the for loop working as that should work. The context processors method is interesting but I have not been able to get anything to work with that other than printing to the screen the results of the db query.

I really do appreciate you trying to help though.

Comment: Thanx for your appreciation.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Tip for everyone. The above solution is for those, who want to have some data always available somewhere all throughout the website. E.g: Navbar dropdown list. 
Or else, you will have to pass the query results always from all views.

Thanks Anshuman. Super solution.

Comment: Happy to help @Arindam

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some problem in the name of the 'key' that you are passing in the context.

In  ReleaseView the context object name is all_releases, while you are trying to iterate on "all_artists".

Even if these changes not work, you can always try running your code on a normal view instead of the a generic view and pass the context in the template.

Comment: Look at the **Question** once again. He has a `ArtistView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. I have just tried to simplify it by printing out two test list items. "test1" shows up but "test2" doesnt

and it looks like an issue with my "for loop" but im not sure what the issue is.

`code`
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                {% for artist in all_artists %}
                    <li>test2</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
`code`