# How to manage a dynamic menu with Django?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views, django-2.1

I would like to create the links of the menu dynamically based on the Category models. I've used DetailView and ListView for create a list and detail page of a single category and it run fine.

Now I would like to see in base.html a new link in a "dropdown" menu every time the user add a new Category.

This is **base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block head_title %}Test{% endblock head_title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'list_tag' %}">Tag</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Category
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              {% for category in category_list %}
                <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.category_name }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </li>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
      <!-- INIZIO corpo centrale -->
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock content %}
      <!-- FINE corpo centrale -->
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is **list_category.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block head_title %}Elenco Categorie | {{ block.super }}{% endblock head_title %}

{% block content %}


  {% for category in category_list %}
    <h1><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.category_name }}</a></h1>
    <hr>
  {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

This is **views.py**

```
class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category_list'
    template_name = "list_category.html"


class SingleCategory(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = "single_category.html"
```

When I use the code in base.html it was shown an empty menu. 
How I can resolve?

> ***UPDATE:***

Using the solution of @ans2human in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279768/bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-populated-with-database-entries-in-django-2), I've created a file **context_processors.py** like below:

```
from .models import Category

def blog_menu(request):

    link_menu = Category.objects.all()
    return {
        'link_menu': link_menu
    }
```

Then I've added the string in **settings.py**:

```
'blog.context_processors.blog_menu',
```

The new strings of dropdown menu are these:

```
<li class="nav-item active dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper" id="img"></i> Blog
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></i> {{ link_menu }}</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Now I've this situation in the menu [image]

It seems that  work but not correctly. How I can resolve?

Comment: In views  missing queryset

Comment: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2017/12/when-and-how-use-django-listview/

Comment: The presence or the missing of the queryset isn't the problem. I've added the queryset but nothing is changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UPDATE 2

**Good news!**
Since I'm not a django expert, I had a trivial difficulty. By reasoning a little more, I found the solution.

Below the solution:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      {% for link in link_menu %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ link.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ link.category_name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
def get_url(self):
    return reverse('product-by-category',args=[self.slug])
    
{% for menu in links %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{menu.get_url}}">{{menu.category_name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value